# Arranging items in a array with a sorted pointer-list

Tags: algorithm

Imagine you sort a list of pointers to a list of items to prevent expensive swaps of the items at the first place. How could you rearrange the items according to the pointer-list *in place* with the fewest steps without any external memory ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorting an array can be seen as applying a permutation on said array.

Rearranging your items in place is akin to performing transpositions (meaning you swap items).
Your problem is then equivalent to the following: given a permutation, how can I write it as a product of transpositions, with the smallest possible number of transpositions.

This problem is described in length [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2975036?seq=1) and [here](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/0025570X.1992.11996014). If you don't feel comfortable with math papers, you can ask this very question on the [math stack exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/).